# I wish to add the new div in PDP page after price section in mageno 2

Tags: price, magento2.2.6, product-view, page

I have added custom div in `/var/www/html/pot/app/design/frontend/pot_customization/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml`.

The div displays for all the products and works fine. But if a product have special price,the div displays two times near price .

Please provide me a solution to add my custom div after the price section.

**default.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>

<?php /** @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\Amount $block */ ?>

<span class="price-container <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
$block->getAdjustmentCssClasses() ?>"
    <?= $block->getSchema() ? ' itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer"' : '' ?>>
    <span class='your-price'>Your Price</span>

    <?php if ($block->getDisplayLabel()): ?>
        <span class="price-label"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
            $block->getDisplayLabel() ?></span>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <span <?php if ($block->getPriceId()): ?> id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
    $block->getPriceId() ?>"<?php endif; ?>
        <?= ($block->getPriceDisplayLabel()) ? 'data-label="' . $block->getPriceDisplayLabel() . $block->getPriceDisplayInclExclTaxes() . '"' : '' ?>
            data-price-amount="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
            $block->getDisplayValue() ?>"
            data-price-type="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
            $block->getPriceType() ?>"
            class="price-wrapper <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
            $block->getPriceWrapperCss() ?>"
    ><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
        $block->formatCurrency($block->getDisplayValue(), (bool)$block->getIncludeContainer()) ?></span>
    <?php if ($block->hasAdjustmentsHtml()): ?>
        <?= $block->getAdjustmentsHtml() ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($block->getSchema()): ?>
        <meta itemprop="price" content="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
        $block->getDisplayValue() ?>"/>
        <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
        $block->getDisplayCurrencyCode() ?>"/>
    <?php endif; ?>
</span>

<!-- custom div start -->
<?php $helper = $this->helper('x\ProductReview\Helper\Data');
?>
<div class="price-guarantee">
    <a href="<?php echo $helper->getBaseUrlData()."why-shop-with-us" ?>" class="guarantee-link">100 % Price Guarantee</a>
</div>
<div class = loyalty-points>
    <span>Loyalty Points<b> 4</b> <span>Learn more about our</span> <a href="<?php echo $helper->getBaseUrlData()."loyalty-points-program" ?>">loyalty points program</a></span>
</div>
<!--  End -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom module and add following files.

> Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" after="product.price.tier" template="Magento_Catalog::afterprice.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/templates/afterprice.phtml

```
<!-- custom div start -->
<?php $helper = $this->helper('x\ProductReview\Helper\Data');
?>
<div class="price-guarantee">
    <a href="<?php echo $helper->getBaseUrlData()."why-shop-with-us" ?>" class="guarantee-link">100 % Price Guarantee</a>
</div>
<div class = loyalty-points>
    <span>Loyalty Points<b> 4</b> <span>Learn more about our</span> <a href="<?php echo $helper->getBaseUrlData()."loyalty-points-program" ?>">loyalty points program</a></span>
</div>
<!--  End -->
```

Replace Vendor and Module wherever needed.